# Is it possible to add a ubuntu user to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Is it possible to add a local user to the my SQL database, I.E. to be able to login to Ubuntu and then Mysql without password as authentication happen on the OS login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
CREATE USER yourubuntuusername@localhost;
```

Now from the command line while logged in as "yourubuntuusername":

```
>mysql
```

Done.